# Django: Add context to TemplateView

Tags: django, django-templates

I have very simple template which I would like to mount via `TemplateView`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('feedback', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='foo/feedback.html', 
                          context=dict(mail=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL)),
                                  name='feedback'),
]
```

But this does not work:

```
TypeError: TemplateView() received an invalid keyword 'context'. 
           as_view only accepts arguments that are 
           already attributes of the class.
```

How can I add render a template without writing a method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [extra_context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.extra_context):

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('feedback', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='foo/feedback.html', 
                          extra_context=dict(mail=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL)), 
                 name='feedback'),
]
```